# How to ORDER the records in a table using counts from other table which is grouped by a column?

Tags: mysql, select

I Have two tables

```
1. Class table
2. notification table
```

class table contains all the details of classes likewise

```
classid | name
 1        myclass
 2        yourclass
 3        ourclass
```

and the notification table contains

```
noty_id | notificationname | class_id
  1         editing               1
  2         insertion             1
  3         answered              2
  4         answered updated      2
  5          deleted              3
```

Above table will yield the counts grouped by classid as given below

```
SELECT class_id, COUNT(*) AS classcnts FROM notification GROUP BY class_id
```

Now I want the class table to be displayed in the descending order of count obtained from notification table, how can i combine both queries to get the result.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT cl.classid, cl.name, COUNT(no.notificationname) AS classcnts
FROM class cl LEFT JOIN notification no
ON cl.classid = no.class_id
GROUP BY cl.classid
ORDER BY classcnts DESC
```

Comment: Hey Marco Why are we grouping it by cl.classid here? rather isnt it should group by "no.class_id:?

Comment: @OM The Eternity: no, because I'm doing a LEFT JOIN and no.class_id could even be null (if there aren't entries in notification table with cl.classid)

Comment: so this query will yeild me the class details from class table sequenced by descending count from notification table?

Comment: @OM The Eternity: I beg your pardon if it doesn't. I cannot test it, but it **should** do the work.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: I've just tested it and I confirm that my query works perfectly!!

Comment: Working like Butterrrr... Thanks @Marco